# php functions and wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm migrating my webpage(s) to wordpress and thus creating a theme. However, the page has a number of scripts (javascript) than need to run. Please may someone clarify my understanding.

To run the scripts I've added them to the `functions.php` file using the format below. I assume **`add_actions`** calls / runs the function. However, will this script run on every page? is there a way of being selective (making some scripts run on page X but not on Y).

========================================================
**Functions.php**

```
function my_theme_scripts_function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() .   '/js/myscript.js');
    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_scripts_function')
;
```

Comment: Under what conditions do you want the script to be included?

Answer (score 1):

In such functions, you can simply grab the current page, and make a conditional processing depending on the id, or any other characteristic of this page. For example let's say you want to apply some script on the page ID 4:

```
function my_theme_scripts_function() {
   global $post;
   if ($post->ID == 4) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js');
   } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_scripts_function');
```

You could also apply this for a page slug, the presence of a meta-data, or whatever...

Comment: thanks poozolax,  I guess I can just define a global variable and fire the function based on the condition.

Comment: just in case you don't already know it (?) the $post variable is a default, already given to you by wordpress each time you load a new page/post/media... So you just have to grab it into your function with _global $post_ and starting from that you can retrieve  everything you need about the loaded page which Wordpress always calls a _$post_

Comment: thanks this is a great help. My final question - is it possible to define any global variable. for example  global $hompg = true;   I assume  global would mean the variable can be accessed from other scripts..  Many thanks

Comment: You can declare any variable you need into function.php as this file is always loaded. On another side you have a bunch of global variables that Wordpress handles for you [some are listed here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) …  

To follow your example, speaking about homepage, it's easier in Wordpress to ask _if (is_front_page())_ than defining a global variable for yourself: this latest snipped will let you know if you're on the front-page defined in the admin panel settings...